# How to properly add and browse images from image folder of web project in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, image, webforms, visual-studio-2017, vs-web-application-project

I created an image folder in my first web application(web-forms) and copied images into that folder, I want to set a background image on div. I followed following steps
opened properties (div) 
1. click style tab
2. select background-image
3. select images folder

But Content folder is not showing any image, its empty. I am beginner and unable to get where I am mistaken. 
[image]

Comment: are you saying that you have your images on the Images folder, the same folder in the visual studio solution explorer?

Comment: An asp:panel, which is a div in html, has a `BackImageUrl` property. But I recommend [using CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include into de project the images you just copied to the images folder. For that you need to click onto the little button to the right of the update (blue one) in the solution explorer top bar and that will show all the files that are not included. Then you select all the images needed -> right click -> include files.

After that repeat the process you did and the imagess should show.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its same folder ?
Reset visual studio and windows , but if you want doing this on code-side

create a css file and look at this code

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/background.png');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Right click on 'Images' folder, click 'Add' add and existing item, then I searched for images folder into project directory and added desired images.